# MSTest-Visual Studio 2022-Test project Models does not reference any .NET NuGet adapter. Test discovery or execution might not work for this project

Tags: mstest, visual-studio-2022

Getting Error after upgrading the versions. I am using MSTest.
Error 1= "Test project Models does not reference any .NET NuGet adapter. Test discovery or execution might not work for this project. It's recommended to reference NuGet test adapters in each test project in the solution."

Error 2 = Sitecore\MyTurfAutomation\MyTurfAutomation\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

[Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi2Em.png)